# Android notification when

Tags: android, уведомления

Делаю уведомления для приложения. Поискав информацию нашёл что это делается через AlarmManager, однако в Build нашёл метод when. За что он отвечает? Вот пример:

```
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("hi")
            .setWhen(when)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: Хм, а разве это не вопрос к документации? [Тык](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen(long)).

Comment: @Other То есть это просто stamp ?

Comment: Ну, судя по докам, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setWhen(long when)
```

Установить время, когда произошло событие. По этому времени будут сортироваться уведомления.

```
setShowWhen(boolean show)
```

Показывать или нет это время в уведомлении